# Execute dataflow jobs consecutively?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, gcloud

How to run apache beam dataflow pipeline synchronously?
Here is the apache beam custom pipeline code (dataflow).

```
def run_pipeline(jdbc_url, username, password, types, wisgen_table, recruiter_table, last_sync_table):

options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
 
last_sync_data = (
 p | "Read last sync data" >> ReadFromBigQuery(
                query='SELECT MAX(time) as last_sync FROM '
                '[wisdomcircle-350611:custom_test_data.last_sync]')
 | "Extract last sync time" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: elem['last_sync'])
 )


wisgen_data = p | "wisgen job" >> ReadFromJdbc (
jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
username=username,
password=password,
driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
query="""SELECT users.id AS user_id, where to_char(users.updated_at,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '{last_sync_data}' """,
table_name="users"
)

recruiter_data = p | "recruiter job" >> ReadFromJdbc(
jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
username=username,
password=password,
driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
query="""SELECT users.id AS user_id, where to_char(users.updated_at,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '{last_sync_data}'""",
table_name="users"
)

wisgen_data | "Convert TableRow to dict(wisgen data)" >> beam.Map(
lambda row: row._asdict()
) | "Write to BigQuery in wisgen data table" >> WriteToBigQuery(
wisgen_table,
write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
schema='user_id:INTEGER,full_name:STRING)


recruiter_data | "Convert TableRow to dict(recruiter data)" >> beam.Map(
lambda row: row._asdict())
 | "Write to BigQuery in recruiter data table" >> WriteToBigQuery(
recruiter_table,
write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
schema='user_id:INTEGER,full_name:STRING'
)

# this must be runs at last when all obove are finished 
_ = (p
| "Create current timestamp" >> beam.Create([{'time': datetime.datetime.utcnow()}])
| "Write to last_sync" >> WriteToBigQuery,
last_sync_tab
schema='time:TIMESTAMP',
write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
run_pipeline(
        jdbc_url='xxxx',
        username='xxxx',
        password='xxxx',
        wisgen_table='wisdomcircle-350611:uat_custom_dataset.wisgen_data_table',
        recruiter_table='wisdomcircle-350611:uat_custom_dataset.recruiter_data_table',
        last_sync_table='wisdomcircle-350611:uat_custom_dataset.last_sync',
    )
```

The pipeline operates asynchronously or completes all job operations in parallel, but I want to first execute the starting job last_sync_data (which is written at the beginning of the above code), and at last, my timstamp (which is written at the end of the above code) job should run when all the above operations are finished.

Can somebody assist me in rewriting the code I have above to meet my needs ?

**requirement**: `last_sync_data` should run first since it retrieves the last sync time.
`wisgen_data` and `recruiter_data` can run in parallel since they are independent of each other.
The last job that writes the current timestamp should run only after all previous jobs are finished.

Comment: Better separate first and last step into a service like cloud run given that both of them are retrieving data but downstream branches are not using them. Then run separate jobs for wisgen and recruiter and monitor them in the same cloud run. Lastly, once all is done, run the final step. That will solve the dependency problem. Plus, you wont be sacrificing the power of Dataflow for dependency based run.

Comment: Hello, @Aishwary Shukla Thank you for the answer. , as I need to pass the last_sync_data output in the query field of below wisgen_data, and recruiter_data , now 
Could you please give a more detailed explanation of the solution?
What I need to accomplish in detail, including how to use cloud run to trigger last sync at the beginning and timstamp at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similar post before.

It's not supported in `Beam` to execute sinks and output connectors synchronously, with native IOs.

If you want having sequence between sinks, it's better to use pipeline orchestration (DAG) with a tool like `Airflow`.

You have a managed solution with [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/composer-versioning-overview).

With `Airflow`, it very adapted to launch two `Dataflow` jobs consecutively.

Unfortunately, `Airflow` and `Cloud Composer` use a `GKE` cluster, and if you don't have many pipeline orchestrations in your use cases, it can be heavy.

You can also use serverless pipeline orchestration with [Cloud Workflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/dataflow/Overview) and Flex Template.

Other solution, if you can't use the previous tools :

- Create a `Shell` script
- In this script, launch the first `Dataflow` job
- Check the status of first job with a polling using `gcloud` command
- When the status of the first job is finished, execute the second `Dataflow` job

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to write two pipelines? You can use [wait_until_finish](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.45.0/apache_beam.runners.runner.html#apache_beam.runners.runner.PipelineResult.wait_until_finish) to finish the first pipeline and then run the second one.

Comment: yes I tried this way like p1 = beam.Pipeline(options=options)  
then p1.run().wait_until_finish() and for second pipeline p2 = beam.Pipeline(options=options) and then 
p2.run().wait_until_finish()  
 but then P2 pipeline is only triggered not P1 one

Comment: Is Airflow one option for your case? Here is the doc: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html#blocking-execution